# php session is not working properly

Tags: php

i have a while loop with buttons with different users , that when clicked they set a session with the respective username, this is what i have inside the while loop:

```
echo'<form method="POST">
            <button name="user" class="usr-frmm-zone-msg" style="">

    <div class="wrp1" style="width:100% auto; height:50px; margin-top:8px; margin-left:10px; overflow:hidden; float:left;">    
    <img src="'.$ff['avatar'].'" width="30px" style="border-radius:50%; margin-top:9px;" height="30px"> 
    </div>

    <div class="wrp1_useri">    
     <p style="font-weight:bold; color:#777777; margin-top:10px;">
     ';   

    echo''.$followed.' ('.$row.')';

    echo'</p>    
    </div>


        </button>';


    if(isset($_POST['user']))
    {
    unset($_SESSION['userchat']);
    $_SESSION['userchat'] = $followed;
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';   
    }
     echo'  </form>';
```

The problem here is that it sets the session only of the first user, even if i click on the last
here is a preview of what im doing https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Gv5.png

Comment: did you start the session at the top ?
using session_start();

Comment: of course... otherwise it wouldn't even set one session don't you think ??

Comment: The fun thing about `SESSION` is that sometimes you need to refresh the page to see the new `SESSION` data.

Comment: i have session_start(); on top...

Comment: but it's not the case, the button has you can see refresh the page xD

Comment: What do you mean with "only the first user" could you explain more.

Comment: im creating a message feature for my website, as you can see here http://i.imgur.com/cRu3mbV.png but even if i click on the last user it adds the session of the first

Comment: where are you getting the user data in `$_POST['user']` I don't see anything in the form to change the username.

Comment: the button is not a submit button, how do you submit the form? even if you did it does not have a value attribute so `$_POST['user']` would be `''`

Comment: Change `<button name="user" class="usr-frmm-zone-msg" style="">` to `<input type="submit" name="user" class="usr-frmm-zone-msg" style="" value="Submit">` and you should be good to go, while removing `</button>`

Comment: THANKS ALOT !  i added an hidden input now it works fine

Comment: Ah that too. There ya go ;)

Comment: ethier add an answer and mark it as solved or let @Fred -ii- do it.

Comment: @Abkarino I think the OP should post their own answer, since mine was based on the submit button.